# Activity to SherlockFragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I want to change my app ( extends Activity ) to Fragment ( extends SherlockFragment )

If I change it I have much errors;

```
public class AlarmClock extends SherlockFragment implements OnClickListener {
```

This is my onCreateView:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {
        // sanity check -- no database, no clock
        if (getContentResolver() == null) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(getString(R.string.error))
                    .setMessage(getString(R.string.dberror))
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    finish();
                                }
                            })
                    .setOnCancelListener(
                            new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .create().show();
            return;
        }
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm_clock, container, false);
        // menu buttons
        add = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibAdd);
        snooze = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibSnooze);

        add.setOnClickListener(this);
        snooze.setOnClickListener(this);
        mFactory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, 0);

        mCursor = Alarms.getAlarmsCursor(getContentResolver());
        mAlarmsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.alarms_list);
        mAlarmsList.setAdapter(new AlarmTimeAdapter(this, mCursor));
        mAlarmsList.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        mAlarmsList.setItemsCanFocus(true);

        mClockLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.clock);

        mQuickAlarm = findViewById(R.id.ibSnooze);
        mQuickAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showQuickAlarmDialog();
            }
        });

        setVolumeControlStream(android.media.AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
        setQuickAlarmVisibility(mPrefs.getBoolean(PREF_SHOW_QUICK_ALARM, true));
        return view;
    }
```

There are a lot of errors because there is no Activity.
If is Activity it works.

**I use "extends SherlockFragment" because I want to add it to the table.**
How fix this problem ? Please help me.

Comment: what errors? Context errors??

Comment: The method getContentResolver() is undefined for the type AlarmClock

The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type AlarmClock

The method finish() is undefined for the type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}

etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If am right, Fragments must definitely be used in an Activity.

So instead of using **this** use **getActivity();** to get the Activity(which uses this fragment) Context.

something like:

```
getActivity.finish();
```

and in case of **findViewById(//some Id);**

use it like this:

```
inflatedView.findViewById(//Id);
```

Comment: inflatedView cannot be resolved.

I must use Fragments because I need use this in Tabs. 

This is my main Activity ( Launcher ) public class ABSTabsViewPagerActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity

Answer (score 1):

A `Fragment` is not a `Context` (unlike `Activity` or `Application`). So quite a few methods are not available to it.

It however has access to the context it is attached to. Usually, you can call `getActivity()` within the fragment to get it. You should check if the `Fragment` is part of the activity by using the `isAdded()` method.

You should do some reading about Fragments, porting existing activities to use Fragments, ... tutorials are available using Google.

Comment: how to use onCreateOptionMenu for ActionBarSherlock when extending SherlockFragment? @MarvinLabs